# Regex: Finding wrong hyperlink in url

Tags: regex

Was looking to see if anyone knew of a way to detect, through regex, mismatched hyperlinks within a link

Example:

www.google.com, in an email, hyperlinked to yahoo.com

www.google.com, pointing to internetbadguys.com

Comment: Also, the format for regex accepted is re2
https://github.com/google/re2

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/<a.*?href=\"http[s]?:\/\/([\w\.]+).*?\".*?>(?!\1).*<\/a>/g`. [Test it online](https://regex101.com/r/udm0R6/2)

Since you have not provided sample code, I have assumed few cases.

Comment: There is no sample code.  This will be a rule i add to my gmail domain to detect hyperlinks that dont much the url within an email

Comment: Btw your post works!

However the regex needed is re2 format 

https://github.com/google/re2

Comment: Backerence is not supported in re2. I can not port my regex without that functionality.